# Tab Bar app with UIwebview, return to normal view

Tags: ios, webview

Me again. Right, in my tab bar application one of my tabs loads a webview and works perfectly. However I want the tab to return to this view when pressed again.

For example, the tab brings up a car sales part of my companies website, should somebody click on the home part of this UIWebView the webview will go there, fair enough I expect this. But when I close the app and reopen or simply navigate away from tab and back again, I want the original page I wanted loaded in the first place. So when the user returns to the app or tab, it resets back to the car sale page and not the last page they left it on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refresh your url in the `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()` function of the viewcontroller.

if not there to override, add one of them in your secondviewcontroller.m file like this:

something like that:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];    

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
}
```

just off the top of my head :)

Comment: How do I refresh? and I dont appear to have them functions in my "SecondViewController" class. I have loadView and viewDidLoad functions.

Comment: i updated my answer. it seems you are missing a lot of very basic things - have you done any tutorials at all?

Comment: Yeah and my app is pretty much complete apart from two things. Reloading the original webview as we're discussing and another fault. Essentially I have 3 tabs, all working fine. In tab A there are buttons which when pressed I hide all info to show new info, I would rather push and pop new screens but this isnt easy. I can push a new view with the whole addSubView method but when I try to pop it off or remove it, it never turns to tabA's original view. I will try your method now and let you know. I obvioulsy write that in the .m file but where is it called? I hate obj-c :(

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! Sorry matey you were right, there was unwritten methods for viewWillLoad() in the class. All sorted.